# How to Call an Event on android softkeyboard back button in Appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am new in appcelerator. I have an issue. I need to call an event when android soft keyboard disappeared by clicking android back button(hardware back button). I can call event when we pressed done/enter button in soft keyboard. But i need to call the event when soft keyboard disappear(by clicking hardware android back button).

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a listener to [keyboardFrameChanged](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-event-keyboardframechanged), with a little of code you can control if the frame change was caused by the appearence or the disappearence of the keyboard.

Comment: Supported platform iOS only.